# Slider with dynamic content is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I'm using Bxslider to display my images and it is working fine for the predefined images.But now, I want to get the images dynamically from the URL.

I used code like:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        onSlideNext : function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
            $.get(myUrl,'',function(response){
                  $('.bxslider').html(response);
            });
      }
    });
```

and it is **appending the images to the slider**, but the slider doesn't include those images.I also tried with `reload` like

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        onSlideNext : function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
            //do your ajax here, for example:
            $.get(site_url + 'content/content/test','',function(response){
                  $('.bxslider').append(response);
                      slider.reloadSlider();
            });
      }
    });
```

but still working.Can anyone suggest me any solution?

Comment: `slider.reloadSlider()`?

Comment: Please see my question.I used it even

Comment: what is returned in response?

Comment: With a simple ul-li is working http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/q5MvW/ ? What is the content of the resposnse

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler2 (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see what is actually being returned to your Ajax get call. If that call fails your reloadSlider() will not be run.

Answer (score 1):

The slider loads slides during initialization. If reloadSlider() was not used then the slider does not know that there is a new slide was added. Also there is a newIndex property that sets the next slide.

> newIndex: element index of the destination slide (after the
>   transition)

So when you click on Next at the end of the slideshow then newIndex=0 and even you will use reloadSlider() you will go to the slide #0. The only way here is to use goToSlide()

```
slider.reloadSlider();
slider.goToSlide(oldIndex+1);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gg2Sk/

Generally speaking, the idea to reload a slider on every new slide is not good at all. You might consider to load initially all slides but do not load images until they are not visible.